# 'start' Docker Container in Interactive Mode after Initial Creation Without Interactive Mode Ubuntu

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu

I have an image that simply uses the latest ubuntu image as the base image.

[image: Dockerfile]

**Goal:**

I would like to create the container without starting it in interactive mode. After creation, I then want to start it in interactive mode.

**Problem:**

If I create the container with the run command ***without*** interactive mode, I am unable to start it later in interactive mode.

When I attempt to start it in interactive mode after creation, the container starts and stops without giving me access to the CLI.

**Question:**

What is the reason for this behavior?

```
PS ...\linux_project> docker images

REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE  
hubusername/ubuntu   latest    b9db0844ba2c   26 hours ago   77.8MB

PS ...\linux_project> docker run -it --name ubuntu_si hubusername/ubuntu

root@f8a5cfe9a8e2:/# exit
exit

PS ...\linux_project> docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES    
f8a5cfe9a8e2   hubusername/ubuntu   "bash"    8 seconds ago   Exited (0) 5 seconds ago             ubuntu_si

PS ...\linux_project> docker start -i f8a

root@f8a5cfe9a8e2:/# exit
exit

PS ...\linux_project> echo yay!
yay!

PS ...\linux_project> docker run --name ubuntu_sni hubusername/ubuntu    

PS ...\linux_project> docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES     
74bcc8ddd336   hubusername/ubuntu   "bash"    6 seconds ago        Exited (0) 6 seconds ago              ubuntu_sni
f8a5cfe9a8e2   hubusername/ubuntu   "bash"    About a minute ago   Exited (0) 49 seconds ago             ubuntu_si 

PS ...\linux_project> docker start -i 74b

PS ...\linux_project> echo I would expect it to launch in interactive mode here
```

**Legend:**

**ubuntu_si** - stands for Ubuntu container initially **started** with interactive mode

**ubuntu_sni** - stands for Ubuntu container initially **not started** with interactive mode

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to need this sequence; do you need to separately `docker create` and `docker start` the container?  I pretty much never use `docker start` FWIW, if I need to restart a container I `docker rm` it and `docker run` a new one.

Comment: The process does not **need** to follow that sequence, but I found the behavior odd. @DavidMaze